# How do I parse through transaction data to determine buys/mints/sells (wallet tracker)

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, python

Please take it easy on me, i'm new to coding and just trying to learn.

I am trying to make a simple wallet tracker (when a specific address mints/buys/sells) it will notify me.

Sounds easy, but i'm struggling trying to figure out the easiest way to do this.

I have created and hosted my own eth node on my secondary PC using rocketpool/geth - it's working great, I can make calls to ask for balances etc, I have it so when a new transaction appears on one of the wallets, it will notify me of a new transaction, but I just cant seem to filter through the transaction information to determine if this address is buying, selling or minting NFTs. I would love some guidance, it would mean alot!

(everything i'm doing has been done in python using web3.py)

thanks so much